# Windows Phone 8.1 & Admob SDK for WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, sdk, admob

i wanted to ask if it's just me not getting any adds (NoFill error) or the admob sdk should actually be update to wp8.1?

```
        <GoogleAds:AdView AdUnitID="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXX/YYYYYYYY"
                      Format="Banner"
                      FailedToReceiveAd="OnFailedToReceiveAd"
                      VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,-23,86" />
```

What might be alternative ad platform solutions that do work on wp 8.1 ?

Comment: you could go with the bing ads from the pubcenter. https://pubcenter.microsoft.com/

Comment: any resolution to this yet?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows Phone (Updated 09/05/2014)

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fba0c64e-358e-4b86-8e69-d6b57771d92a

Admob not work on Windows Phone 8.1 yet, only on Windows Phone 8 or Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/5WyPFuMGKig/xGnh_nw8nQgJ

Comment: Mew ... What a bummer. I can't use  pubcenter (Microsoft's ad network) since I live in Indonesia, which is not supported by pubcenter (no Indonesia on the dropdown list for 'where do you live' question). Any suggestion other than smaato and adduplex? I already use both.

Comment: Microsoft Pubcenter is almost worthless anyways. It's fill rates and payouts are nearly nothing compared to adMob.