# How to display admob ads in Windows Phone 8.1 XAML (RT) Apps?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, admob

I recently upgraded my Windows Phone App to Windows Phone 8.1 XAML version. I was using admob SDK earlier in Windows Phone 8 SilverLight App, So I was in am assumption that admob SDK will be available for XAML Apps also. Its only now I came to know that there is no official admob sdk support for this version. So, is there any official way or tweak(workaround) to show admob ads in the App?

Comment: Possible duplicate...see (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23163309/windows-phone-8-1-admob-sdk-for-wp8)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the ad rotator control on github
https://github.com/Adrotator/AdrotatorV2